# Using JS to display XML as a table in HTML only shows one row

Tags: javascript, html, xml, html-table, row

The code below only shows the first row of the table, it does not show the remaining elements of the XML file.  I have no idea why.

**Edit:** I see part of the problem is that vegTable is a variable.  I need a function in the for loop.

**Edit 2:** I can now increment the table to get the proper amount of rows, but the first row of data is all that displays, multiple times.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7Vmb/)

```
function getVeggies() {
"use strict";
var veg, sci, vegTable;
veg = (cc[dd].getElementsByTagName("veg")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
sci = (cc[dd].getElementsByTagName("sciname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

for (dd = 0; dd < cc.length; dd++) {

vegTable += "<tr><td>" + veg + "</td><td>" + sci + "</td></tr>";
}

document.getElementById('fullTable').innerHTML = vegTable;
dd = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example xml string and set up a jsfiddle

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7Vmb/) That is the XML and the full JS script, more or less.  I fixed my incrementing issue by changing vegTable = to vegTable +=, but now it only shows the first row four times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the element getting logic into the loop:

```
function getVeggies() {
    "use strict";
    var veg, sci, vegTable;
    var cc = cc;//whats cc?

    for (var i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) { 
        veg = (cc[i].getElementsByTagName("veg")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        sci = (cc[i].getElementsByTagName("sciname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

        vegTable += "<tr><td>" + veg + "</td><td>" + sci + "</td></tr>";
    }

    document.getElementById('fullTable').innerHTML = vegTable;
}
```

Comment: That is it!  Thank you!  'cc' is a global variable.